# How to execute diff on the command line using Go?

Tags: bash, go, command-line-interface

I'm having a problem using Ubuntu 14.04 and executing `diff` on the command line. Look at the following Go code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "os/exec"

func main() {
    output, err := exec.Command("diff", "-u", "/tmp/revision-1", "/tmp/revision-4").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

If i execute this using `go run test.go` i get the following error:

```
2015/03/18 14:39:25 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

So something is going wrong with `diff` and it's returning `1` as its exit code. Only the `diff` command seems to throw an error. If i use the `cat` or `wc` command, the code runs fine.

Any ideas why `diff` doesn't work here but other commands do?

Comment: Do those files differ? Because an exit status of `1` from diff means some differences were found not an error. `2` is error from `diff`. This is documented in the man page.

Comment: Yes they are different and everything works fine in bash.

Comment: The log.Fatal* exits the program immediately when you see a non-0 exit status. You're not getting to where you print the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run a program with `exec`, you get an error if the exit code was not 0. From the doc:

> The returned error is nil if the command runs, has no problems copying stdin, stdout, and stderr, and exits with a zero exit status.
>
> If the command fails to run or doesn't complete successfully, the error is of type *ExitError. Other error types may be returned for I/O problems.

So what happens here is that diff returns an error when the files are different, yet you treat it like a runtime error. Just change your code to reflect that it isn't. It's possible by checking the error.

e.g. something like this:

```
    output, err := exec.Command("diff", "-u", "/tmp/revision-1", "/tmp/revision-4").CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
           
        switch err.(type) {
        case *exec.ExitError:
            // this is just an exit code error, no worries
            // do nothing

        default: //couldnt run diff
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
```

Also, I've changed it get `CombinedOutput`, so if any diff specific errors occured, you'll see stderr as well.

**Note** that you'll get a "valid" error even if one of the files doesn't exist. So you can check the `ExitError`'s exit code by doing something like this:

```
    switch e := err.(type) {
    case *exec.ExitError:

        // we can check the actual error code. This is not platform portable 
        if status, ok := e.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus); ok {
            // exit code 1 means theres a difference and is not an error
            if status.ExitStatus() != 1 { 
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
```

Comment: WaitStatus is the status code from wait, not just the exit code.  Use `ExitStatus()` to get the actual exit code, so it will be a 1 as documented, not 256.

Comment: @JimB where is this ExitStatus call? The API docs I have (and code completion) have nothing of this sort.

Comment: It's a method on WaitStatus: http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#WaitStatus.ExitStatus

Comment: @JimB thanks I'll modify my answer for the sake of generations to come :)